# Deploying Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

When trying to deploy python azure function with the command:

`func azure functionapp publish <appname> --build remote`

I'm getting the error:

> Unable to connect to Azure. Make sure you have the `az` CLI or `Az.Accounts` PowerShell module installed and logged in and try again

I have already deployed using this command before, but now for some reason it refuses to cooperate.

I have tried re-installing the Azure CLI and have run `az login` to successfully login.

Comment: May I know the version of your python ?

Comment: Try `Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts`

Comment: Python version is 3.6.6

Comment: Got the following error when trying to install Az.Accounts: `The following commands are already available on this system:'Login-AzAccount,Logout
-AzAccount,Resolve-Error,Send-Feedback'. This module 'Az.Accounts' may override the existing commands. If you still wan
t to install this module 'Az.Accounts', use -AllowClobber parameter.`

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error, managed to pass it after running command:

```
az login
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was solved by explicitly stating the tenant ID and subscription ID that I want to login to. Apparently it happened because my user exists in two different tenants.
Just run before the func command:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "tenant-GUID" -SubscriptionId "subscription-GUID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be broken as azure cli and azure function core tools do not seem to like each other anymore on my machine.

I managed to publish by installing azure cli and azure function core tools in Windows subsystem for Linux. Just worked in Linux without issues at all...